# Getting user's group name in Windows

Tags: java, windows, usergroups

I'm using a Java program that has to gather info that can be derived from the user's group.

How can you get a user's group name from windows?  Is it found in a file or is there some method/API for getting it?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific about the information you're trying to get.

Comment: i just need the user name and group name.  I'm not sure how groups work in windows, but that might be that name of the administrator group or user group.

Comment: Users can be members of multiple groups, so there is no "user group".

Comment: still, is there any way to get the group or groups that a user belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

This forum post [Naming and Directory (JNDI) - JNDI, Active Directory and Group Memberships](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=581444&messageID=3313188) should put you on the right track.

Comment: this looks like it gets info from ldap servers...will this do the job for windows groups?

Comment: If you are trying to access a windows 2000+ server than yes, Active directory is an LDAP server.